# How to show a loading image until the page body background image loaded?

Tags: jquery, html, css, pageload

We need to show a loading image until the page large size of background image is loaded. This bg image will be called to body tag in the HTML file not through CSS.

Comment: adding more images to fix the issue of having images that are too large to begin with is maybe the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Display image here
}


$(window).load(function(){  
    //remove image
});
```

So you display an image when the document is ready

And finally you  remove the image when the page is loaded completly

Comment: //Display image here (we cannot write here a particular image, so we mentioned this background image will be called from body html tag)

Comment: The display image here would be your loading image